# change in values of an array

Tags: c, opengl

I am having trouble in the part of the code creating 1 column mesh.

i am creating 2 arrays having co-ordinate values. x coordinates are stored in x array and y coordinate values in y array. the problem is: though i am modifying the values of the array x, it is having some other values and i am not getting req output.

i want the distance between 2 x coordinates as 60 but i'm getting some other value.

Try this code and tell me where i've gone wrong.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<GL/gl.h> 
#include<GL/glu.h>
#include<GL/glut.h>


void drawBitmapText(char *font,char *string,float x,float y) 
{  
    char *c;
    glRasterPos3f(x, y,0.0);

    for (c=string; *c != '\0'; c++) 
    {
        glutBitmapCharacter(font, *c);
    }
}

void drawBitmapInt(char *font,int i,float x,float y)
{
    char buffer[10]={'\0'};
    char *c;

    sprintf(buffer, "%d", i);

    glRasterPos3f(x, y,0.0);

    for (c=buffer; *c != '\0'; c++) 
    {
        glutBitmapCharacter(font, *c);
    }
}       

void MainMem()
{
    int i,j,xo=100,yo=0,k=12,x1[2],y[12];
    int dx=60,dy=50;

    for(j=0;j<13;j++)
    {
        y[j]=0;
    }

    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        x1[i]=xo+i*dx;
        printf(" %d %d", x1[0],x1[1]);
    }   
    x1[i]=0;
    for(j=0;j<13;j++)
    {
        y[j]=yo+j*dy;
    }
    y[j]=0;
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);


    for(j=0;j<13;j++)
    {

        glColor3f(0,1,0);
        printf("\n%d %d",x1[0],x1[1]);
        glVertex2i(x1[0],y[j]+260);
        glVertex2i(x1[1],y[j]+260);
        glVertex2i(x1[1],y[j+1]+260);
        glVertex2i(x1[0],y[j+1]+260);

    }

    glEnd();


    for(i=0;i<1;i++)
    for(j=0;j<13;j++)
    {
        drawBitmapInt(GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_18,k--,x1[0]+730,265+j*50);
    }
}

void displayPoints()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(0.1,0.7,0.1);    
    MainMem();
    glFlush();
}   


int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutCreateWindow("SampleGL");
    glutInitWindowSize(2000,1000);
    glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    gluOrtho2D(0.0,2000,0.0,1000);
    glutDisplayFunc(displayPoints);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: `j<13` --> `j<12` so elements 0..11 will be accessed (which are 12 elements).

Comment: Don't repeat the same hard-coded number, use `#define Y_SIZE (12)` and then use `Y_SIZE` all over your code instead of just `12`. Much easier to avoid stupid mistakes.